# convert a list to data frame without messing with data

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a list data like this

```
library(Matrix)
   
myd<- new("dgTMatrix", i = c(3L, 4L, 4L), j = 0:2, Dim = c(5L, 3L), 
        Dimnames = list(c("Xkr4", "Rp1", "Sox17", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1"
        ), c("AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1", "AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1", "AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1"
        )), x = c(1, 2, 1), factors = list())
```

I am more comfortable to work with data frame than list, so I am trying to convert it to a data frame but I am not sure if I am destroying the structure or not

I simply do

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(myd)
```

then it becomes like this

```
mydf<- structure(list(`AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 2), `AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Xkr4", 
"Rp1", "Sox17", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1"))
```

Do you think there is a safer way to convert such a data?

I tried to understand the data, so if I `unlist` it, it will look like below, but still I am not sure of converting

```
unlist(myd)
5 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
       AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1 AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1 AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1
Xkr4                    .                  .                  .
Rp1                     .                  .                  .
Sox17                   .                  .                  .
Mrpl15                  1                  .                  .
Lypla1                  .                  2                  1
```

Comment: If you're using libraries not that are not in the default environment please always include them in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First off, calling `as.data.frame(myd)` where `myd` is an object with class `dgTMatrix` throws an error as shown below:

```
library(Matrix)

myd<- new("dgTMatrix", i = c(3L, 4L, 4L), j = 0:2, Dim = c(5L, 3L), 
          Dimnames = list(c("Xkr4", "Rp1", "Sox17", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1"
          ), c("AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1", "AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1", "AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1"
          )), x = c(1, 2, 1), factors = list())

as.data.frame(myd)
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(myd): cannot coerce class 'structure("dgTMatrix", package = "Matrix")' to a data.frame
```

The reason for this is that there is no `as.data.frame` method defined for `dgTMatrix`. However, there is an `as.matrix` method defined for `dgTMatrix` as well as an `as.data.frame` method defined for class `matrix`. So, if your best course of action really is to be transitioning between `dgTMatrix` and `data.frame` (which I feel it may not be), you probably want to do something like:

```
library(Matrix)
   
myd<- new("dgTMatrix", i = c(3L, 4L, 4L), j = 0:2, Dim = c(5L, 3L), 
        Dimnames = list(c("Xkr4", "Rp1", "Sox17", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1"
        ), c("AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1", "AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1", "AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1"
        )), x = c(1, 2, 1), factors = list())

mydf <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(myd))
mydf
#>        AAAGTAGAGATGCCAG-1 AACCGCGTCCAACCAA-1 AACTCCCGTCGGGTCT-1
#> Xkr4                    0                  0                  0
#> Rp1                     0                  0                  0
#> Sox17                   0                  0                  0
#> Mrpl15                  1                  0                  0
#> Lypla1                  0                  2                  1
```